# Spring boot: ConfigurationProperties with map

Tags: java, spring, configuration

Using spring boot 2.7.7. Can't get working mapping configuration into `Map<String, Integer>`

This is my application.yml

```
limiter:
  settings:
    a: 1
    b: 2
```

My class with properties:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "limiter.settings")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LimiterSettings {
    private final Map<String, Integer> settings;
}
```

And this is how I try to use it:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(LimiterSettings.class) // doesn't affects
public class LimiterService implements ILimiterService {
    @Autowired
    public LimiterSettings limiterSettings;
```

As a result have empty map.
Works fine if use just `int` fields with corresponding names in `LimiterSettings`.
Please help what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the yaml file given in the question it should be:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "limiter").
```

Comment: oh, true! it's for separate fields within class it should be `limiter.settings`, but not for `settings map`, thanks )